# prometheus server throwing data does not end with # EOF

Tags: java, rest, prometheus

I am exposing my application metrics using simple text based exposition format as specified here [EXPOSITION FORMATS](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/).
The output from my http endpoint is below

```
user@host-ubuntu:~/scripts$ curl -X GET http://172.17.0.23:8181/rest/metrics 
# HELP my_new_metric my_new_metric
# TYPE my_new_metric gauge
my_new_metric{container_id="xyz",container_name="blah",instance="abc",job="blah"} 0
user@host-ubuntu:~/scripts$
```

There are newline characters after HELP, TYPE and the metric
My https server's java code is below

```
    public String metrics() {
        return "# HELP my_new_metric my_new_metric\n" +
                "# TYPE my_new_metric gauge\n" +
                "my_new_metric{container_id=\"xyz\",container_name=\"blah\",instance=\"abc\",job=\"blah\"} 0\n";
    }
```

But the Prometheus server is logging the following warning and  my metric is not being collected.

```
level=warn ts=2021-02-12T14:45:16.377Z caller=scrape.go:972 component="scrape manager" 
scrape_pool=kubernetes-pods target=http://172.17.0.23:8181/rest/metrics
 msg="append failed" err="data does not end with # EOF"
```

How do I add EOF to my String? Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: I don't know Prometheus, but to me it looks like you're sending commands in the form `# COMMAND argument ...`, e.g. you're sending the two commands `# HELP` and `# TYPE`, and that you should take the error message literally, i.e. read it as `data does not end with "# EOF"`, which means you need an extra line with `"# EOF\n"`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but the issue was the wrong http response header. Problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was missing the `@javax.ws.rs.Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` annotation on the REST interface and the http response header was by default marking the response as octet string.

issue got fixed once i put the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

add the `produces = "text/plain"`:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/metrics", produces = "text/plain")
```